# Power BI DAX measure calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

[image]Step1:

I have created a calculated table containing `Level`, `Location`, `L2code` from level sales data. I need to create a report that will count rows based on the `level1` group.
Note that there are more levels in the table. This is only an example of one of the levels.

How can I count the rows for each level1?

Step2:

I need to create all combinations of counts based on location and l2 code and count the numbers.
like in example 2 location and 8 distinct l2code so it should be 2*8 =16 total possible rows.

How can I achieve this using the DAX measure?

Source data file

[image]

Output report

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one is a simple measure as below-

```
DistinctRowCount = Count(your_table_name[Level1])
```

Second one is bit tricky and you can try this below measure-

```
CrossCount = 

var distinct_location = 
calculate(
    distinctcount(your_table_name[Location]),
    allexcept(
        your_table_name, 
        your_table_name[Level1], 
        your_table_name[Location]
    )
)

var distinct_l2code = 
calculate(
    distinctcount(your_table_name[l2code]),
    allexcept(
        your_table_name, 
        your_table_name[Level1], 
        your_table_name[Location],
        your_table_name[l2code]
    )
)

return distinct_location * distinct_l2code
```

Sample output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Rabbani. I am going to start test. I will be back soon after that.

Comment: It is working this part. Now. I will beg some more deeper solution that would be absolutely helpful for me .

Comment: It is working this part. Now. I will beg some more deeper solution that would be absolutely helpful for me . The source table is a calculated table.  As a source i am using this summarized calculated table and this table i would like to use inside the count calculation. How can i do this?

Comment: Added summary table i have used as a source. If you could help me that would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance and appreciate.